# Is there any way to dodge McCree's ultimate?

Tags: overwatch

Might be a noob question but as far as I know, it can only be *dodged* by hidding **behind a wall** or **shield** (*not even sure about the last one*) so I was wondering if there's any way of *dodging* it, for example, doing the **jump with Pharah** or the **dash with Genji**.

Comment: No real noob questions on this IMO as the game has only been out a day. It's a fine question :)

Comment: Not a real answer, but *killing* the McCree is always an option - and with the latest update, it's a wasted Ult on his part too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Other than breaking line of sight, there is no general way of "dodging" it. There are character specific skills you can use to avoid it.

- Reaper - Wraith Form
- Mei - Ice Block
- Genji Deflect(will generally one shot the mcree or anyone else you're targeting while deflecting btw, damage is based on the time the mcree channels before firing.)
- Reinhardt/Winston/Zarya shields seem to work as well, though I've never done this myself.

Basically anything that can make you immune to projectile damage should work, if timed properly. Otherwise, your only option is to kill him first or break line of sight.

Comment: Reinhardt shield will block it.  Not sure about Winston shield but logic says that it should.

Comment: Any type of barrier will stop McCree's bullet, see [here](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/McCree)

Comment: I believe both of them and zarya shields all work the same, so I imagine they do, which is why i listed them, I just never tested it myself.

Comment: "Including teammates" cannot possibly be correct. I do not believe that.

Comment: You may be correct, after looking back to where I am sure i saw him killing teammates mentioned and shown, I was misremembering how it went. The deflection becomes "fired by genji" so teammates would be immune.

Comment: It won't one shot anyone it's deflected toward (Genji). I'm pretty sure it will deal damage corresponding to the time it has been channeled on you. so if McCree activates it quickly it might not one shot the tank you are redirecting it towards.

Comment: Good point, Ill add that note.

Comment: Lucio's Sound Barrier ultimate will also make it take longer for Deadeye to deal a killing blow as it temporarily adds 500 shield-type armor to all nearby allies.

Comment: Also, Zenyatta's Transcendence ultimate will make him invulnerable during the duration of it.

Comment: D.Va's *Defense Matrix* is capable of removing the *Deadeye* shot, just like Genji. Also, Tracer's *Recall* makes herself invulnerable during the return, so Tracer is (though hard to pull off intentionally) capable of dodging *Deadeye*.

Answer (score 4):

- You can dodge it by getting out of line of sight.  When MCree enters High Noon he gets a visible glow around his body. Take cover behind walls or buildings where you know he can't lock-on to you.

  - You will see a tumble weed right in front of McCree while he is using Deadeye.  This is only a visual effect, but this can perhaps help the enemy in locating you quicker by spotting the tumble weed first.
- Some abilities can completely block his ult, such as Reinhardt's shield, Genji's deflect, Mei's Ice Wall, and D.Va's Defense Matrix
- Teammates can also block your shots for you, provided they have enough HP to tank the damage McCree dishes out

  - In High Noon, Mcree locks on to enemies, and it takes a specific amount of time to lock on.  The longer you lock on, the more damage it does, up to the max HP the hero has, so at full lock-on, you will instakill the enemy.
  - If a teammate who has not been locked on has jumped in front of a teammate as Mcree fires, he can tank up to however much damage the Mcree has dished out to that hero
  - Example: Tracer is locked on by Mcree.  Since she only has 150 hp Mcree locks on rather quickly.  A Zarya, hiding out of sight, jumps in front of the Tracer as Mcree fires.   As Zarya has 400 hp (200hp/200shields), she will take 150 damage from the Mcree that was intended for Tracer as well as whatever damage the Mcree also locked on to Zarya.

Answer (score 1):

The most team friendly way of dealing with McCree's ultimate is to kill him before he gets his shots off. It sends him back to spawn with 50% ultimate charge so he then has to build it up again before he can make his next attempt.

Answer (score 0):

- Become invulnerable.

  - By timing it right, Tracer's *Recall* is capable of dodging *Deadeye* from its innate invulnerability frames, although hard to pull off intentionally.
  - Zenyatta's *Transcendence* is also possible of pulling off this, but judging by the nature of this ultimate, it is not recommended to do it intentionally.
  - Mei can use *Cryo-Freeze*.
  - Reaper can use his *Wraith Form*. Bonus for getting out of the heat.
- Get out of sight.

  - Mei's *Ice Wall*, when properly used, will hide the targets.
  - Targets behind Reinhardt's *Shield* and inside Winston's *Shield Projector* cannot be targeted.
  - Zarya's *Projected Barrier* or *Particle Barrier* can also "conceal" the target from being targeted by *Deadeye*.
  - If everything fails, just hit the deck!
- Return it to the sender.

  - Genji can *Deflect* the shot back to the enemy team.
  - D.Va's *Defense Matrix* will also remove the shot.
- Neutralize the shooter.

  - Although Reinhardt's *Charge* or *Earthshatter* can stun him out of McCree's ultimate, judging by the nature of those skills, it is **not** recommended to use them to neutralize him.
  - Roadhog can *Chain Hook* McCree to stun him out of his ultimate.
  - Allied McCree can *Flashbang* the enemy McCree while *Deadeye*'s active.
  - If everything fails, **kill him outright!**

Answer (score 0):

The only way to survive (not dodge) his Deadeye is to try shooting the McCree. With luck, he might panic and fire his Deadeye prematurely (before it's fully charged). This will only work if he has not already completed his charge. (It's not the ONLY way, it's just a way to not get killed if you are using a hero who doesn't have a defensive special move.)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked...