# How does McCree's Deadeye work?

Tags: overwatch

How does McCree's Deadeye work and how do buffs and debuffs affect it?

I've been reading up on some other questions and answers

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/288157/137983

[McCree's Deadeye Damage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/270025/137983)

[Is there any way to dodge McCree's ultimate?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/266637/137983)

But nothing definitive about how it works.

From what I've read, Deadeye charges up power at 170 dmg per second but when do buffs affect Deadeye, while he is charging or when he shoots?

Do enemies need to be in view during charge or can McCree hide in a dark corner seeing no one charge to the last second then popout and shoot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

McCree's ult works by charging damage as you said. The outter circle shrinks until it reaches the inner one.

In the video, first clip, you clearly see that the circle suddenly shrinks when mercy damage boosts McCree. However, when Mercy unbuffs him in the second clip, the circle retracts for a split second (due to bad synchronization mainly). Meaning that the only buffs that matter are those active when McCree actually shots.

Enemies need to be in sight of McCree for the channel on them to begin. When the second activation is done, everyone in sight will be killed.

You can just stay in a corner and then pop up, but your ult will do next to no damage as it couldn't charge enough.

Comment: Pretty sure that if you break LOS before he fires you will survive. The bullets do not seek around corners

Comment: If you break line of sight before he fires THE FIRST bullet, you are safe. Otherwise it's not the case. I.E. McCree has 5 targets lined up, you are the fifth one to be shot and get behind a wall while the first one is shot, you are still dead.

Comment: @Karlyr I'm dubious of that claim. If a reaper or Mei can invuln the damage by using their ability when the trigger has been pulled, then I'm almost certain you can dodge out of sight. It takes about two thirds of a second for the Deadeye sweep to reach you if you're on the opposite side of the screen than the first target, which is enough time to get behind cover if you're close.

Comment: @Karlyr That goes against what I've experienced both playing as and against McCree. I've had it happen a number of times where I'll see three skulls on my ult, pull the trigger, and only get two kills. Similarly, I've dived behind cover right as a McCree flank-ults our team and survived (though this happens less often).

Comment: I'm 95% sure the ult will not hit you if you're the last target and you've run out of his LoS. The bullets are only hit scanned at the time of fire. If the second he let his ult fire you were guaranteed dead genji reflecting his ult would not stop you from dying even though McCree is dead. It's possible that the favor the shooter aspect of the net code mixed with hit scan makes you feel like you've died in an unfair manner or around a corner.

Comment: Talking about "assumption behind the code", get some video evidence please. I'm tired of this "I know I'm right" arguing.

Comment: @Karlyr I see in the edit history that you clarified and then removed the section that would have addressed my comment. It is possible that the netcode is making it look like cover is not helping after he begins firing, or  instead it is the case that firing is an atomic action regardless of where each target is in the queue.

Comment: @JamesCW I completly removed it because everyone in the comments were disagreeing, yet not bringing any facts to the table. I removed the section altogther until we have some proof.

Comment: @JamesCW and to be fair, the only reason why I'm still sticking to my guns (and not removing the comment stating it) on that one is because I saw that I was completly hidden in the kill cam (netcode is out of the way)

Comment: @Karlyr Keep in mind that the kill cam view is a reconstruction using the record of game actions, and is not strictly 1:1 to the player's actual movements and actions.

Comment: If it is "using the record of game actions", it means that it is the server POV. Which means it would make no sense for me to have died unless the acquisition of the target was made prior to my personnal shot from the ult. Anyway, unless we have definite proof I'm leaving everything as is.

Comment: This concept of damage charging was also very visible duirng the junkenstein's revenge event, due to ana boosts being in play and the mercy/reaper/junkrat/roadhog bosses having absurdly high health pools and taking an age to lock onto at full health